# AdMob ad filters, and revenue

Tags: android, admob, setting

I don't realyy understand this part about money revenue. What is neccesary to earn money, should ads juyt be diyplayed, or users must click on it ??

And second about that ad filters, should I leave it on default settings, or better to change it ??

Answer (score 1):

You can earn money from impressions (ads being displayed) but it is very small amounts per thousand impressions. You will earn slightly more from clicks.

Don't filter unless you have personal (eg ethical/moral) or competitive objections to the type of content being displayed to give yourself the best chance of earning revenue.

Comment: And what is that thing about Google AdSense ads... should I turn it On or Leave it Off ??

Comment: If you mean the "Use Google ads and Google certified ad networks to improve fill rate." setting then that means you will get adverts from Google as well as Admob. As Google own Admob I can't see the difference. It might well give you a bigger audience but I don't think you can filter the Google ads like you can Admob. See http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307264&topic=1307248&ctx=topic

Comment: @Goran How do you know you are shutdown? Do you mean your app(s) has/have been removed from the market or your admob account has been disabled?